# Multiple SQL Update Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have thousands of SQL update statements that need to be performed on a large table. The update statements take several minutes to execute, and I need to run these in a more efficient way if possible in order to speed it up.

What options exist to make these updates faster?

Running on SQL Server 2008 R2

One such query:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET Col1 = 'abc', Col2 = 123, Col3 = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
WHERE ID = 123456
```

Comment: First option is to show us some structures and sample query

Comment: Show us one of those UPDATE statements.

Comment: UPDATE myTable SET Col1='abc', Col2=123, Col3='2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' WHERE ID = 123456. The ID column is the Primary Key. Columns are of different types (one can assume they are the same column names but different values for all queries)

Comment: First thought would be to find a way to expand your where clause to pick up more cases where the update is needed.  How does this example differ from one of the other updates you are doing on another ID?

Comment: The column values are often different...

Comment: How are you determining what the column values should be? Are they based on values from another table, or a calculation, etc?

Comment: Make a reasonable number of UPDATE's per transaction. Not one transaction per update, and perhaps not all updates in one huge transaction.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS systems are optimised for bulk operations, not updating rows one at a time like this.

To speed up an update in general, check if there are any triggers which may unnecessarily run on update, or if you've got lots of unnecessary indexes which are updated when the row values are.

Is it possible to work out what the new values will be in advance at the database end, for example are they based on a calculation or another table, something which could be calculated in bulk on the database side? One update statement that does some transformation is much better than updating rows individually.

If this is a user or program updating the values, so you have no way to know what the new values will be, consider redesigning your front end to cache values in a way which allows you to then update the database in bulk later on.